# Frobenius norm product with two inequalities

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

I have the Frobenius norm of two products, $\lVert AB\rVert_F$ and $\lVert AC\rVert_F$. $A$, $B$, and $C$ are matrices, the dimensions do not matter as long as they are compatible and $B$ and $C$ have the same size. I know that $\lVert B\rVert \leq \lVert C\rVert$, is there any inequality I can obtain with the original two norms (e.g. $\lVert AB\rVert_F \leq \lVert AC\rVert_F$, or anything else)?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.

Comment: @copper.hat I agree. I'd like to know if there are very general results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=B=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}$ and $C=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&2}$. Then $\|B\|_F=1<2=\|C\|_F$ but $\|AB\|_F=1>\|AC\|_F=0$.

Comment: Would this still be the case assuming that both $C$ and $B$ are not in the kernel of $A$?

Comment: @FrancescoCarzaniga This doesn't matter. In the above example one may perturb $A$ by a small $\epsilon I$ to make it nonsingular. Then $\|AB\|_F$ will be close to $1$ and $\|AC\|_F$ will be close to zero, so that $\|AB\|_F$ is still larger than $\|AC\|_F$.